# R Shiny - How can I dynamically add to a table without using global variables?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, dt

How can I achieve the same functionality as the below example, without using global variables.
I suspect the answer might have something to do with the 'reactiveValues()' function but I can't get it to work.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("selectMe", "Select Something", list(A="A",B="B",C="C",D="D",E="E")),
  actionButton("pressMe", "Add Something"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("theTable")
)

someThings <<- isolate(data.frame())

renderTable = function(input) {
  DT::renderDataTable({
    currentSelect = isolate(input$selectMe)
    if (input$pressMe > 0) {
      currentThings = someThings
      newThings = rbind(currentThings, data.frame(SelectedThing = currentSelect))
      someThings <<- isolate(newThings)
      newThings
    }
  })
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$theTable = renderTable(input)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggestion of `reactiveValues` is a good one, however since we only want to hold one variable (the `data.frame`), we can also use `reactiveVal`. All we require next to that is an `observeEvent` that listens to the button click. Working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("selectMe", "Select Something", list(A="A",B="B",C="C",D="D",E="E")),
  actionButton("pressMe", "Add Something"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("theTable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  my_df <- reactiveVal(data.frame())

  observeEvent(input$pressMe,ignoreNULL = T,ignoreInit = T, {
    currentThings = my_df()
    newThings = rbind(currentThings, data.frame(SelectedThing = input$selectMe))
    my_df(newThings) # set the new value of the reactiveVal.
  })

  output$theTable = renderDataTable(my_df())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope this helps!